# How do I output leading zeroes in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there anyone who knows how can I can display:

- "01" instead of "1"
- "02" instead of "2"

When the number is < 10.

Below is my code.

```
%%[
set @Duree2 = field(@row2,"Duree")
set @hours2 = FormatNumber(Subtract(Divide(@Duree2,60),0.5),"N0", "en-US")
set @minutes2 = Mod(@Duree2,60) 
]%%
%%=v(@minutes2)=%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the [**format()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm) function.  Something like this:

```
%%[

var @num
set @num = 2

output(concat("<br>num: ",format(@num,"00")))

set @num = 12

output(concat("<br>num: ",format(@num,"00")))

]%%
```

**Output**

```
num: 02
num: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit weird, but the best way I have found is via CONCAT() and an IF statement. See below:

```
%%[
SET @varnum = 2

IF Length(@varnum) < 2 THEN

    SET @formatnum = CONCAT("0", @varnum)

ENDIF

]%%

%%=v(@formatnum)=%%
```

OUTPUT: `02`

I noticed you seem to be doing Hours and Minutes. If you are looking to do a full date/time string, you may want to check out [FormatDate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm) and [Format()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm) functions.